# Python code does not work because of bool values

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
            'Fee': ['False', 'False', 'True','False','False','False','False', 'False','False','True','False','False','False']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

    ID    Fee
0    1  False
1    1  False
2    1   True
3    1  False
4    1  False
5    1  False
6    2  False
7    2  False
8    2  False
9    2   True
10   2  False
11   2  False
12   2  False
```

I would like to add a column in which every row before the value 'True' in the 'Fee' column is 0 and every row after it is 1. It does not matter if the 'True' value receives a 0 or 1.
So it should look like this:

```
    ID    Fee  Bool
0    1  False     0
1    1  False     0
2    1   True     0
3    1  False     1
4    1  False     1
5    1  False     1
6    2  False     0
7    2  False     0
8    2  False     0
9    2   True     0
10   2  False     1
11   2  False     1
12   2  False     1
```

I figured out it can be done via the following code:

```
df['Bool'] = df['Fee'].eq('True').groupby(df.ID).cumsum().astype(int)
```

However, if I read the same table of an CSV and do it, it does not work as then the 'Fee' column is then not an `object` anymore but a `bool`. The 'Bool' column is then just filled with 0s.
I know I can just convert the column to another type and then redo it, but I am just curious about why this happens?

Comment: "I know I can just convert the column to another type" ... wouldn't that be the appropriate thing to do here? Objects-that-look-like-booleans just seem wrong.

Comment: @BigBen  I wrote that I am just curious. But I do not understand what you mean? If a read a CSV with this table in Python, then the 'Fee' values are actually booleans.

Comment: Sure, but clearly you're working with objects here. So, convert them to boolean.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, I know that I am working with objects and this way it actually works. And then when I convert them to boolean the code does not work. Try it out.

Comment: I did try it. `df['Fee'] = df['Fee'].eq('True')`, then `df['Bool'] = df['Fee'].eq(True).groupby(df.ID).cumsum().astype(int)`. Works for me.

Comment: @BigBen `eq(True)` is not needed (unless you have an object dtype with things other than `True`/`False`), and OP also wants to `shift` ;)

Comment: @mozway good point on the `eq(True)`, but note that "It does not matter if the 'True' value receives a 0 or 1."

Comment: @BigBen my bad then, I missed that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df['Bool'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Fee']
                .transform(lambda x: x.shift().eq('True').cummax()
                                      .astype(int)
                          )
             )
```

*NB. if Fee contains real booleans and not strings, remove the `.eq('True')`.*

Output:

```
    ID    Fee  Bool
0    1  False     0
1    1  False     0
2    1   True     0
3    1  False     1
4    1  False     1
5    1  False     1
6    2  False     0
7    2  False     0
8    2  False     0
9    2   True     0
10   2  False     1
11   2  False     1
12   2  False     1
```

Comment: Thank you! Removing the `.eq('True')` from `df['Bool'] = df['Fee'].eq('True').groupby(df.ID).cumsum().astype(int)` just solved the problem! Your code works with the 'object' values, but removing `.eq('True')` when working with real booleans gives me the error 'cannot convert float NaN to integer'. :)

Comment: Then your real dataset is not like the shown input. What is the output of `df['Fee'].unique()` in the real data?

Comment: I just did it with the example I posted here and not my real dataset. It works here as the 'Fee' column is an 'object'. Transforming the 'Fee' column with `df['Fee'] = df['Fee'].astype('bool')` (then `df['Fee'].unique()` gives `ID   int64 Fee   bool Bool   bool
dtype: object`) and using your code (without the `.eq('True')`) gives me the error message.

Comment: This is not the output of `df['Fee'].unique()` but of `df.dtypes`

Comment: Oh, sorry I wanted to write both but combined the outputs by mistake. So `df['Fee'].unique()` gives `[True]` and `df.dtypes` `ID   int64 Fee   bool Bool   bool dtype: object`. :)

Comment: ok, so you have true booleans, you shouldn't use `.eq('True')`. Can you edit your question with the output of `df.to_dict('list')` (on the original `df`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Bool'] = df['Fee'].eq(True).groupby(df.ID).cumsum().astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not work either, it just leads to 0s in the 'Bool' column.

Comment: Sorry. Corrected my answer. It should work now